# Create a custom classifier that works with ML.Net Pipelines

Tags: c#, .net-core, ml.net

I have an in house developed application and would like to incorporate the ML.Net machine learning library with a custom classifier. In particular, how do I make a custom classifier that works with the `LearningPipeline` class? How does one make a custom classifier when doing so means abiding by the `ILearningPipelineItem` interface which requires `Microsoft.ML.Runtime.EntryPoints.Var` as a property despite `Microsoft.ML.Runtime.EntryPoints.Var` being a sealed class?

Answer (score 0):

`LearningPipeline` is not meant to be extensible. There is no easy way to add a custom classifier.

You could take a look at the new API (start [here](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/docs/code/MlNetHighLevelConcepts.md)), and implement an `IEstimator<ITransformer>`, which you will then be able to plug into the pipeline and `Fit`.

It is going to be possible, but still not exactly easy.